# Windows Networking Setup

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2012-r2, subnet, network-printer

I work at a small veterinary business, and because I am the only one with any technical background I have defaulted into being our poor excuse for a sysadmin. I don't know enough about networking, but I'm trying to pick it up fast.

We got a new server through the vendor of our practice management (PM) software. Now that the server is in place, I'm getting much more paranoid about the rest of our setup; I know it's not great, but I don't know enough to fix it properly. I have a few specific questions about what to do.

1. **Firewall:** We currently have a DSL modem connected directly to our only router / wireless access point. I think we need a firewall (more than what's available on the router) in between these, but I'm not 100%. The router is consumer-grade, and probably needs to be upgraded to business class. Given that our web site is externally hosted, and almost all of our traffic is internal (we do need internet access, though), what type of firewall should I be looking for?
2. **WiFi:** Our new server is running Windows Server 2012 R2 as a Hyper-V VM. The VM is mainly just an SQL server for our PM software, but it has also been set up as the domain controller (previously we were just using a workgroup), DHCP server, DNS, and has a few shares set up for what little non-SQL file sharing we need. I got all of our ~10 workstations (wired and wireless) set up on the new domain, and they are working well. What are not working are the staff's various wireless devices. They're allowed to browse the Internet, and were previously connected via a guest WiFi network on the router. Because I've turned off the router's DHCP in favor of the server, the guest network no longer has much meaning. It seems like some phones receive IPs, but even those are not able to browse. I've temporarily fixed this by reserving static IPs outside the IP pool of the DHCP server for the phones directly on the router, and setting phones to assume that IP and use 8.8.8.8 for DNS. I *think* the longer-term solution to this is a separate router/AP for non-domain devices. Is that correct, or is there something I could do to avoid that (our router doesn't support VPNs) using our current setup? If I *do* get a new access point, what should I be looking for? We have a few domain Surface Pros that use WiFi as well, so I need to be able to separate them.
3. **VMs & Subnets:** We have another physical server for our digital x-rays. This is a *very* low-traffic server. It is currently not set up as part of our domain, nor is the x-ray acquisition workstation. The PM workstations do access this server to view the x-rays. I'd like to get rid of this physical machine and get this onto the new server machine. If I do this, should I put it on the same VM as our main SQL server, or set it up as a new VM (we are limited to 2 Hyper-V VMs). If I do the latter, how should I go about setting up the network for the second VM? I'm inclined to create a new subnet for this server and workstation just to regulate them separately, but I don't know enough about networking to know if that makes sense. If it's not on a separate VM, can it be set up with a separate subnet? Would it make more sense just to create separate groups on the domain for the practice management machines vs. the x-ray machines?
4. **Printers:** We have several printers which attach to the network directly via WiFi, and one older one that is shared by one of the workstations. I reserved IP addresses for the WiFi printers in DHCP setup, and verified that the printers are getting the expected IPs, but the printers' availability as seen by the workstations has been spotty since the switch to the domain. I know next to nothing about setting up a print server, but is this something I should be doing for these printers? Would it be OK for the print server to be on the same VM as the AD/DHCP/DNS server? The printer physically connected to a workstation has been working wonderfully. If I do set up a print server, should I include that printer too?

Thank you in advance for any help, and I will try to provide any additional details needed. I have a lot of more-general questions, but I'm trying to keep these specific. Any recommendations for a decent beginner sysadmin reference would be great, too (esp. in book form, which I know is old-fashioned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) A dedicated firewall would probably only be feasable if you are communicating to external servers on a lot of different ports besides HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443). The firewall code within your router is probably fine, as long as it's been patched recently. Check the manufacturer's website - any patches for security vulnerabilities will be posted there.

Keep in mind that the "DSL Modem" is likely also a router/firewall/access point in its own right, and depending on the provider, may offer features you can use.  It also can present problems if it also includes a DHCP server (as it may be allocating addresses in the same range as your main router/DHCP server). Your internal router has probably already worked out routing thru this device, so you shouldn't need to mess with that. A second firewall may present issues if you're opening any ports for specialty traffic, since you will also need to open them on the modem.

2) WiFi/DHCP issues : see above.  If you have delegated DHCP tasks to your server, you might need to go into the router settings and set up a DHCP proxy service to provide DHCP to the devices attaching via WiFi. This simply relays DHCP requests (which are normally 'broadcast' on a local subnet) to another system on another subnet.  WiFi to wired may be different subnets, or they may not - it depends on how your router/access point is set up.  You also might want to disable WiFi and DHCP on the DSL modem if it has the capability, because if it's accepting connections, it may also be farming out IP addresses, ones that  conflict with existing assignments.  This will cause connectivity drops as IP conflicts shut down their respective NIC's.

3) VM vs Physical Server - this question is a bit of a "risk management" problem. On the one hand, your database, DC, DHCP server, and so on are all running on the same virtual system on the same host, so if it or the host should go down, your entire operations network is pretty much toast. So adding the X-ray system as another VM isn't really going to be a game changer from what it is now. However, as a physical system, I am assuming that, should the rest of the network (all on your Hyper-V server) go down, the X Ray server would still be able to scan, print, and manage X-rays. You also need to find out if the scanner drivers are compatible with a VM run under Hyper-V. If they're not, then you cannot virtualize the scanner.

As for different subnets/domain groups, this is probably a trivial matter for the size of the office -  I'd say not to introduce complexity if you don't absolutely have to.

4) Printers... on WiFi. In a medical office, with multiple wet-walls, radiation shielding for X-ray equipment, and cinderblock and metal pet cages.  Ouch. Putting aside the routing issues you already have with your tablets, and the static IP kludge you used to get the phones working, having on-demand devices such as printers connecting via Wi-Fi in this environment makes me wonder how they work at all. Seriously. Get those on the wired network, even if it means running Ethernet up inside the walls and across your drop ceiling.  They'll be much more reliable. As for the print server, I'd say yes on that. It'll make managing your printers so much easier (plus you can pool them such that if one is out of paper or toner or whatnot, jobs can be sent to another).  You can put that role either on the main VM, or utilize the underworked X-ray server as a print server.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response. I hadn't thought to check the configuration on the DSL modem, but I will look into that.    As far as the DHCP proxy, our current router doesn't seem to have that capability ([R7000](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/R7000)). As long as the phones don't pose a risk to the rest of the network, I'm OK using the static IP/DNS setup. I'll definitely hook up the printers to the ethernet and look into setting up a print server.